# Show fields from res.partner and product.product - OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, odoo

On `sale` module, you got objects `sale.order` and `sale.order.line`, On treeview of sales, you got `sale.order` object, to show fields from that model.

Now, i'm trying to show one field, for example `product_id`  which is on `sale.order.line`, i know i can use `fields.one2many` then `many2one`, but it's not working, not showing anything, so i don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

I did already this kind of job before on OpenERP, but it was long time ago and I jsut forgot the right way to accomplish this...

Here's a piece of my code (interesting part)

on `sale.order`

```
'linea_tarifas':fields.one2many('sale.order.line', 'tarifas', 'Servicio'),
```

On `sale.order.line`

```
'tarifas' :fields.many2one('sale.order','Servicio'),
```

What i'm trying to achieve, is to inherit all fields from `sale.order.line` so i can show any of them into `sale.order` tree view.

This is my xml `sale_view.xml`

```
<record id="view_order_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.tree</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="priority">2</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Sales Orders" fonts="bold:message_unread==True" colors="grey:state=='cancel';blue:state in ('waiting_date','manual');red:state in ('invoice_except','shipping_except')">
                <field name="message_unread" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="name" string="Order Number"/>
                <field name="date_order"/>
                <field name="partner_id" />
                <field name="lider_id"/>
        **<field name="linea_tarifas">**
        **<field name="product_id"/>**
        **</field>**
                <field name="user_id"/>
                <field name="amount_total" sum="Total Tax Included"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="view_quotation_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.tree</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="priority">4</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Servicios" fonts="bold:message_unread==True" colors="grey:state=='cancel';blue:state in ('waiting_date','manual');red:state in ('invoice_except','shipping_except')">
                <field name="message_unread" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="name" string="Numero de Servicio"/>
                <field name="date_order"/>
                <field name="partner_id" />
                <field name="lider_id"/>
        **<field name="linea_tarifas">**
        **<field name="product_id"/>**
        **</field>**
                <field name="user_id"/>
                <field name="amount_total" sum="Total Tax Included"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

The `linea_tarifas` is the related field, but it's not showing anything.

I hope I've explained myself.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for that, please check out `sale/sale.py and sale/sale_view.xml` file. Their is `one2many is order_line` and `many2one is order_id`, in your case you have `one2many is linea_tarifas` and `many2one is tarifas` You will get clear idea where you do wrong.

Comment: Hi, I'll dig it, thanks!

Comment: Well, it is actually almost the same, i don't know, maybe i should use 'fields.related' on the fields i want to show, can't figure it out...

Comment: for `fields.related`, you may refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332654/related-type-field-not-showing-value/23332844#23332844